# Is there a possibility to get the selected Time from a <TimePickerField> component?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript-vue

I´m writing a Nativescript-vue app for a Time-Tracking Project. 
I use TimePickerField for this but it doesn´t work actually.

I already tried to v-model my time to a variable "selectedTime".
But when I log the variable, i get an undefined.

```
 <TimePickerField locale="de_DE" hint="From..." pickerOkText="Ok" pickerCancelText="Cancel" pickerTitle="Choose" v-model = "selectedTime"></TimePickerField>
```

It should log the selected Time but i get: "selectedTime is undefined".
Does anybody work with this TimePickerfields and know how to handle them.

Here is the documentation of this component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-datetimepicker

Comment: I didn't see `v-model` being used in the npm page examples, but I saw [this example](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-datetimepicker/blob/master/demo-vue/app/components/Home.vue#L16), where you use `@timeChange="onDateTimeChange2"` to set the value `this.dateTime2`. Maybe this example can help you out

Comment: thank you very much, i just started to use this and i have overlooked it :)

Comment: It happens, especially when you start and there is a lot of new stuff to learn and track. Good luck!

Comment: It works fine with @timeChange but i have another question. Do you know how to handle TimePickerFields in Listviews? Do you know how to differentiate between the TimePickerFields in a ListView in the "onDateTimeChange" - handler? Is there a way to pass an id or something like that? Thank you